# gnome-terminal doesnt open

Tags: python, gnome-terminal, symbolic-link

I decided to update python from 3.10.? to 3.12.0 (downloaded and compiled), after that i noticed my terminal doesn't start. Tried several solutions but no luck, i run terminal commands in visual studio code. After several hours of trying to find a solution, I learned the hard way that it is not wise to change the current python version in ubuntu.

Here is my terminal output;

```
elan@elanozturk:~/Desktop$ sudo update-alternatives --list python
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.10-config
/usr/bin/python3.12

elan@elanozturk:~/Desktop$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3): /usr/bin/python3.12
Nothing to configure.

elan@elanozturk:~/Desktop$ sudo update-alternatives --list python3
/usr/bin/python3.12

elan@elanozturk:~/Desktop$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
elan@elanozturk:~/Desktop$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.18
elan@elanozturk:~/Desktop$ python3 --version
Python 3.12.0
elan@elanozturk:~/Desktop$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/share/python
elan@elanozturk:~/Desktop$ whereis python2
python2: /usr/bin/python2 /usr/share/man/man1/python2.1.gz
elan@elanozturk:~/Desktop$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
elan@elanozturk:~/Desktop$
```

Is there any painless way to revert python version back or fix the symlink?

Comment: You can install many python3 versions, but do not change the default for a Ubuntu Desktop system, as many default apps & tools rely on it (eg. `gnome-terminal`) and them not working is actually better than them working incorrectly and corrupting data!  Revert your changes & return the default python3 for your *unstated* Ubuntu product/release and your system will work correctly (*and not corrupt data*).